# Razor2 WebPage post document.createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

I am working on a Razor 2 Web Page form. Some elements, to wit: a series of select elements, are created by jQuery and appended to a div based on checkbox selections. Those elements appear on the page's UI and work as expected, but they do not in the page's source view. 
My problem is that i cannot seem to retrieve the values from these elements.
Other elements, modified by Razor at page load, work perfectly.
Any ideas on how to get the values of elements created on a javascript event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that you add a `name` attribute value to form elements if you want to reference their values on the server following a `POST` or `GET` request. It is the `name` value that acts as a key in `Request.Form` and `Request.Querystring` collections. If you do not provide a value for `name`, the item is not included in the collection.

Comment: My javascript did add a name attribute to the elements created. However, once i realized i could get a look at the resulting elements using Chrome's Inspect element function, i found the names were not well formed. I changed my code to correct this, and now they work as expected.
Thanks for pointing me to what i needed to be looking for.